# How can I remove one Form from InLineFormSet, before form.Is_valid() ? Django

Tags: django, inline-formset

I have one inlineformset:

```
formsetItens = ItensInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=vPedido)

if formsetItens.is_valid():
```

I like to remove from formsetItens one form, before my `is_valid()` command.

how can I do that?

Comment: you should not be doing this. What are you trying to achieve? There might be a cleaner way to accomplish

Comment: I try to remove if I selected one bool field.. where can I do this?